# If $a \pmod n = a'$ and $b \pmod n = b'$, prove that:

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer greater than $1$. 
If $a \pmod n = a'$ and  $b \pmod n = b'$, prove that:

1. $(a+b)\pmod n =  (a'+b') \pmod n$
2. $(ab)\pmod n =  (a'b') \pmod n$

So far I have that

If $a \bmod n=a'$, then there exists $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a=a′+kn$. If $b \pmod n=b′$, then there exists $m \in \mathbb Z$ such that $b=b′+mn$. Therefore,

$$a+b=a′+kn+b′+mn=a′+b′+(k+m)n$$

Hence, $(a+b)\pmod n=(a′+b′) \pmod n$.

As for the product,

$$ab=(a′+kn)(b′+mn)=a′b′+a′mn+b′kn+kmn2=a′b′+(a′m+b′k+kmn)n$$
Thus, $ab \mod n=a′b′ \pmod n$.

I feel like this is an incomplete answer. Is it correct?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the mod operator? What work have you done on this problem.

Comment: So, what does it mean that two integers are congruent $\mod n$ and what is your difficulty with these two statements? You early need to think as much of this through as you can, because if you don't get why this is true, you will likely struggle later on. You really need to ask a question which will aid your understanding.

Comment: i put in my work

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \equiv a'\pmod n$ then there is a number $r$ such that $a = a' + rn$. Similarly for $b$, there is a number $s$ such that $b=b' + sn$.

1. $(a+b) = a'+rn + b'+sn = (a'+b')+(r+s)n \equiv (a'+b')\pmod n$
   since for every two natural numbers $x \leq n$ and $t$, we have $x+tn \equiv x \pmod n$
2. $(ab) = (a'+rn)(b'+sn) = (a'b' + a'sn + b'rn + rsn^2) = a'b' + (a's+b'r+rsn)n \equiv a'b' \pmod n$ The last equality follows from $a'$,$b'$,$r$,$s$ and $n$ all being natural numbers.

EDIT: This is actually pretty same approach as yours. But it is done independently of your proof.